# Sorting a hashmap based on 2 values of an object key

Tags: java

For example,

```
Map<Testing, Integer> xx = new EnumMap<>(Testing.class);

public enum Testing {

    EXAMPLE_1(1, 2);
    EXAMPLE_2(2, 100);
    EXAMPLE_3(2, 20);

    public int position;
    public int value;

    public Testing(final int pos, final int value) {
        this.position = pos;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I would want to sort the hashmap based on the Testing itself, we could ignore the value of the hashmap here.

Basically, sort based on position in descending, followed by value in ascending

```
xx.put(EXAMPLE_1, 1111);
xx.put(EXAMPLE_2, 1111);
xx.put(EXAMPLE_3, 1111);
```

I want the result to return as {EXAMPLE_2, EXAMPLE_3, EXAMPLE_1)

I've tried using a Collection to sort twice but it doesn't seem to work as it only takes part in the last sort

```
Eg: 
    Collections.sort(Map, new DescendingPosition());
    Collections.sort(Map, new AscendingValue()); // only this applies
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT*
Here's what i've tested, and it works, is there any shorter way which can be done?

```
    Map<Testing, Integer>[] hi2 = new TreeMap<>[3];
    for (Entry<Testing, Integer> hmm : statups.entrySet()) {
        final int pos = (hmm.getKey().position - 1);
        if (hi2[pos] == null) {
            hi2[pos] = new TreeMap<>(new CompareValue());
            hi2[pos].put(hmm.getKey(), hmm.getValue());
        } else {
            hi2[pos].put(hmm.getKey(), hmm.getValue());
        }
    }
    Map<Testing, Integer> finalMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i = (hi2.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) { // to arrange positions in descending
        if (hi2[i] != null) {
            finalMap.putAll(hi2[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(finalMap);

    public static class CompareValue implements Comparator<Testing> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Testing o1, Testing o2) {
            return o1.value - o2.value;// ascending values
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` is unordered, and [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) works only on `List`s.

You might want to use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead of a `HashMap` here, **but it is sorted according to keys [and not values!]** [I am not sure I understand, but if you are trying to sort according to the key, you can just make your class implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) or implement your own [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), and `TreeMap` will probably best fit here].

An alternative is **using [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)** [and have to do some more work]. `LinkedHashMap` maintain elements at the order you inserted them, so you will have to maintain it by yourself. Note that if you have frequent insertions - it is expected to be not efficient, since the maintanance of this structure will consume a lot of time.

Comment: But kinda curious here, when I used a TreeMap before, some of the data is gone, let say i add 3 into it, and only 2 are added in.

Comment: @Nature: maybe you had 2 values which were equal, according to the `Comparator`? If it is the case - the first was overriden by the second... The same thing accures in `HashMap` - if two object `equals()` each other.

Answer (score 0):

A HashMap is unordered, so you can't keep one sorted.
But assuming you just want to extract the keys from your HashMap in a sorted order, use `Collection.sort(yourMap.keys(), new MyComparator())` where MyComparator compares both the values you want to sort on.

Write a Comparator that sorts on both values, something like:

```
  public class MyComparator extends Comparator<Testing> {

    public  int compare(Testing a, Testing b) {
         if(a.position < b. position)
             return -1;
         else if(a.position > b.position)
            return 1;
         else { //position is equal, sort on value
            if(a.value < b.value) 
                return -1;
             else if(a.value > b.value)
                return 1;
         }

         return 0;

      }  
  }
}
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mkyHTThL, here's what i got, but it doesn't seem to fix the values which i want

Comment: I don't thinks its possible, as the result is 1, 3, 2, 4, 5. And when i reverse it, its 5, 4, 2, 3, 1.
It should be 4, 5, 3, 2, 1

Comment: If you want the order to be descending on the position part, and ascending on the value part, adjust the `<` and `>` accordingly. This one compares ascending on position and value.

Comment: Can you describe which values you want to sort on ? You have A) An enum composed of 2 values, position and value. B) An integer that's the value part in your Map, where an enum maps to that integer. What do you want to sort on, and in which order ?

Comment: A) based on the positions in descending, once the positions in descending is sorted, the positions for the object's positions must be fixed, then only sort the object's value in ascending. As for "B)", which is the integer which is in the map, will follow where the key goes

Comment: Here's a compilable sample that gives the order you mentioned in the post though: http://pastebin.com/Hc0anH5n

Comment: Ahh yes, this is the one which fits what i wanted, but if I want to print it into a hashMap again with the values paired with it before?
Use xx.get(t).getValue() and make a new hashmap again or..?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of HashMap you should use TreeMap with your custom comparator like this:

```
public enum Testing {
    EXAMPLE_1(1, 2),
    EXAMPLE_2(2, 100),
    EXAMPLE_3(2, 20); 
    public int position;
    public int value;

    Testing(final int pos, final int value) {
        this.position = pos;
        this.value = value;
    }

    static class EnumCompare implements Comparator<Testing> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Testing arg0, Testing arg1) {
            return arg0.value == arg1.value ? 0 : arg0.value < arg1.value ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }

    // Testing
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Testing, Integer> xx = new TreeMap<Testing, Integer>(new EnumCompare());
        xx.put(EXAMPLE_1, 1111);
        xx.put(EXAMPLE_2, 1111);
        xx.put(EXAMPLE_3, 1111);

        // prints: {EXAMPLE_2=1111, EXAMPLE_3=1111, EXAMPLE_1=1111}
        System.out.println(xx);
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost work, but doesn't seem, http://pastebin.com/ZacqxUEU, let say if i shuffle the hashmap, and didn't put in order, it returns me as {EXAMPLE_5=4444, EXAMPLE_2=222, EXAMPLE_3=11133331, EXAMPLE_4=4444, EXAMPLE_1=1111} instead of 4, 5, 3, 2, 1

Comment: Are you still using HashMap? I am not. Your ex still gives me `{EXAMPLE_5=4444, EXAMPLE_2=222, EXAMPLE_3=11133331, EXAMPLE_4=4444, EXAMPLE_1=1111}`

Comment: I used the TreeMap like what you've shown above, but basically, once the positions are sorted, it should be fixed, then only sort the values in it, but when i use your method, it just sorts the position, then when it sorts the value, the positions are messed up again.

Comment: I see your code and it very different from my code. 1. Look at my comparator. 2. Why are you using LinkedHashMap, your finalMap can be TreeMap like I showed in my code. 3. Not sure what is `statups`.

Comment: statups is the enumMap which contains the Testing.EXAMPLE_1, and so on. But when I use TreeMap for finalMap, the main positions will get shuffled again..Oh and, your Comparator doesn't check for the pos of the Testing data

Comment: To create a TreeMap from EnumMap just do: `Map<Testing, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<Testing, Integer>(new EnumCompare()); treeMap.putAll(statups);` Your comparator is definitely incorrect and it also doesn't look at position field and I have to admin that you code is very difficult to understand.

Comment: The position field is arranged in descending order under the for loop, (int i = (hi2.length - 1); i >= 0; i--), yes but if I used treeMap.putAll(statups), only the values are arranged, the position doesn't take account.

Comment: Good to see you problem solved, can you accept this answer now.